# Expo router.push works only when passing string directly

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

In my Expo app when I pass string directly to `router.push()` like below it works

```js
<Button onPress={() => router.push("../chat/index")}>
    Select
</Button>
```

but when I pass string from props

```js
interface Props {
    href: string
}

<Button onPress={() => router.push(href)}>
    Select
</Button>
```

I got the error

[image]

I also tried this

```js
interface Props {
    href: string
}

<Button onPress={() => router.push({ pathname: href })}>
    Select
</Button>
```

but I got the same error

I am using

```json
"expo": "~50.0.8",
"expo-router": "~3.4.8"
```